# How to set bee / bat unit timeline to be unavailable by default?

Tags: bookings, 8

As in question. I'm using bee (based on bat) module. Currently all time is green, available for booking. My task is to allow user to select availability period first, then allow bookings only in specified time slots.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I'm on the same struggle.

Comment: I made user available to make bookable event as well (an admin/specialist) - then I just ignore this dynamically created event by bat (bat_id = 0) inside calendar widget (custom). So customers can book only on manually created bookable events